# React unable to access tensorflow model under Public folder

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, github

I have a react app with a tensorflow model for image classification. Everything was working fine until I restarted my laptop.

1. The react app was working fine on local laptop
2. I deployed the react app to github pages. The app was working fine both on
   github and locally. i.e able to find the model folder.
3. Restarted the laptop, opened the react project locally in vscode and now
   react is not able to find the tensorflow model in the public folder

The below error appears when I trigger the classiyImage function within the react app.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your path should be `'/static/image_classification_model_v1/model.json'`
or
`process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/image_classification_model_v1/model.json'`

Comment: this works locally process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/image_classification_model_v1/model.json' 

But why did we have to add process.env after deploying react to github? But when i push the changes to github still get the same error.

Comment: check your js after deploy and you will se that process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/image_classification_model_v1/model.json' becomes '/static/image_classification_model_v1/model.json' thats how build process of CRA works, more about it here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: check js mean? The react works fine locally but still have error after pushing the changes to github

Comment: sorry, the github pages took time to refresh. working fine both locally and on github. Thanks